# Validate list depending on other field in form asp.net core 2

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation, asp.net-core-2.0

I have a form that has an int field and a list of another form (class). I want to validate the forms inside the list depending on the int field.

The `int field` can have the values 1 or 2. In case of 2, validate the list forms, else, do not (I don't need the list forms).

The problem is, I cannot find any way to get that int field value in the other form. The `ValidationContext` object only has the instance of the actual class, not the parent one (the main form).

I have created a custom validation on the `int field` to clear the list in case that his value is 1 (I don't need the list to be validated).

The problem with the latest one, it does the tick (it clears the list) but, the `ModelState.IsValid` returns false, and I do not see any error message.

If I delete the custom validation, it shows the validation errors of the forms in the list that are required.

```
public class ReserveForm
{
    [Required]
    [DataMember]
    [Range(1, 2)]
    [OnTypeValidation]
    public int type { get; set; }

    [MultiFlights]
    public List<MultiFlightForm> multiFligths {get;set;}
}

public class MultiFlightForm
{
    [Required]
    public String from { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public String to { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public override DateTime DateTime { get; set; }
}

public class OnTypeValidationAttribute: ValidationAttribute
{
    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        if ((int)value != 2) {
            ReserveForm reserveForm = (ReserveForm)validationContext.ObjectInstance;
            reserveForm.multiFligths.Clear();
        }

        return ValidationResult.Success;
    }
}
```

As you can see, on the ReserveForm (main form) I have a custom attribute on the list called MultiFlights. The problem with that, is that it only get called when the list is empty or null.

I cannot add custom attributes to do the trick on the fields to the other/sub form (MultiFlightForm), because I cannot have access to the field `type`.

Comment: A `ValidationAttribute` is for validating data. Under no circumstances do you ever alter the data in a `ValidationAttribute`.

Comment: If you do not want any `MultiFlightForm` instances to be posted, the handle that in the client so that none are posted

Comment: So, I have to just remove all the `MultiFlightForm` using JS. There is no other way to do it back end?

Comment: Not unless you were to create a custom `ModelBinder`

Comment: Well, I have created a custom ModelBinder inherited `IModelBinder`. It gave me the expected result. The only problem is that, I have to create the `List<MultiFlightForm>` manually (**I have done it**). But if I add or change the properties on `MultiFlightForm` I will have to modify the custom ModelBinder too. I want to know if is there a class I can call to automatically create the `List` or a `MultiFlightForm` for me.